# How to display javascript object property in my html page.

Tags: javascript

the tutorial i was following always use console.log to display the object property. How to display the object property inside my html document.
Here is my code.im trying to do: http://codepen.io/cyberjo50/pen/vKoXVJ

```
var purchase1 = { item:"fruit" };

function displayDetails() {
document.write(this.item);
}

purchase1.showDetails = displayDetails;
```

Beginner level
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what and how you want to display the data.

The proper way to display JS data in HTML is to have an html element referred by id and set the innerHTML property to the value of the object property, otherwise document.write will clear the document every time you call it

ex:

```
<div id="details"></div>

<script>
var purchase1 = { item:"fruit" };

function displayDetails() {
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = this.item;
}

purchase1.showDetails = displayDetails;

purchase1.showDetails();
</script>
```

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the function, add this at the bottom:

```
purchase1.showDetails();
```

Comment: That won't work, since `showDetails` is not a property of `purchase1`.

Comment: It does work, because they set `showDetails` onto `purchase1` in their example code (`purchase1.showDetails = displayDetails;`)

Comment: Oops, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

or use [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```js
var purchase1 = { item:"fruit" };

function displayDetails() {
document.write(this.item);
}

displayDetails.call(purchase1)
```